# Roslyn: Compile expression with non-public fields from external assembly

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, roslyn

I am working on evaluating of user expressions from debugger. I want to compile expression in method context, and then inject IL-code with debugger.

Is it possible to compile expression, which contains non-public class/class-fields from external assembly to IL-code with Roslyn?

I've got 'MyNamespace.dll' with public class 'Test' and private method 'PrivateMethod', and I want to call it from Roslyn compilation.
I am trying to do it with next code:

```
    public class TestCompilationOptions
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Output.dll");

            Console.WriteLine("Preparing syntax tree");
            string expressionString = @"
using System;

class XXX
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MyNamespace.Test.PrivateMethod(2));
    }
}";
            //SyntaxTree targetTree = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(expressionString);
            SyntaxTree targetTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(expressionString);

            Console.WriteLine("Preparing metadata references");
            Assembly[] assemblys = new Assembly[4];
            assemblys[0] = typeof(MyNamespace.Test).Assembly;
            assemblys[1] = typeof(Console).Assembly;
            assemblys[2] = typeof(object).Assembly;
            assemblys[3] = Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "System.Runtime.dll"));
            MetadataReference[] metadataReferences = MetadataFromAssembly(assemblys);

            Console.WriteLine("Preparing default namespaces");
            IEnumerable<string> DefaultNamespaces = new[] {"System", "System.Runtime"};

            Console.WriteLine("Preparing compilation options");
            CSharpCompilationOptions ReleaseDll = new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary, optimizationLevel: OptimizationLevel.Release);
            CSharpCompilationOptions cOptions = ReleaseDll.WithUsings(DefaultNamespaces);
                                                          //.WithMetadataImportOptions(MetadataImportOptions.All);

            Console.WriteLine("Getting compilation");
            CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("Output.dll", new SyntaxTree[] {targetTree}, metadataReferences, cOptions);

            Console.WriteLine("Emitting compilation");
            using (var dll = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                var emitRes = compilation.Emit(dll);
                if (!emitRes.Success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Emited unsuccessfully!");
                    foreach (var d in emitRes.Diagnostics)
                        Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

    public unsafe MetadataReference[] MetadataFromAssembly(Assembly[] assemblys)
    {
        MetadataReference[] result = new MetadataReference[assemblys.Length];
        byte *b; 
        int length;
        for (int i = 0; i < assemblys.Length; i++)
        {
            if (assemblys[i].TryGetRawMetadata(out b, out length))
            {
                var moduleMetadata = ModuleMetadata.CreateFromMetadata((IntPtr) b, length);
                var assemblyMetadata = AssemblyMetadata.Create(moduleMetadata);
                result[i] = assemblyMetadata.GetReference();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

And got following error:

```
(8,44): error CS0117: 'Test' does not contain a definition for 'privateMember'
```

I've made 'WithMetadataImportOptions' and 'MetadataImportOptions' public inside Roslyn and uncomennted line

```
//.WithMetadataImportOptions(MetadataImportOptions.All);
```

And then got following error:

```
(8,44): error CS0122: 'Test.privateMember' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

So may be it could be done using some Roslyn API?

P.S.
I know, that I can get non-public fields symbols using System.Reflection, but how do I compile the expression then?